# Remove extension of files inside a list

Tags: sed, rename

I have a list "file.list" which contains `.bed` files . I want to remove the extension `.bed` from the "file.list" file

I tried `sed -i 's/.bed//g' file.list` but that doesnt work .

Comment: Are you on a Mac or BSD system?  You may need to add an empty string after the `-i` – `sed -i '' 's/\.bed$//' file.list`

Comment: Does not work in what way? It doesn't do anything, or you get an error?

Comment: Which version of MacOS? `sed` of older versions don't support `-i` at all. Check `man sed` on your machine to verify whether and how `-i` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

To change the contents of the file `file.list` in the way that you describe:

```
sed 's/\.bed *$//' file.list >file.list.tmp && mv file.list.tmp file.list
```

This would work with any implementation of `sed` (the `-i` command line flag is notoriously non-portable between `sed` implementations). It writes the result to a temporary file, and if no errors occurred (like running out of disk space), the original file is replaced by this temporary file.

The expression `s/\.bed *$//` will remove the string `.bed` from the end of each line.  It also allows for trailing spaces (these will be removed too).

---

To rename the actual *files* listed in `file.list`, assuming one filename per line:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    echo mv "$name" "${name%.bed}"
done <file.list
```

The `echo` prevents the renaming from actually happening, you should run this with it in place once first to see if it's working.

The variable substitution `${name%.bed}` will remove `.bed` from the end of the value `$name` (which is a line read from `file.list`).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me you have a list of files within a file.list that you only want rename those files which have .bed suffix and remove from real files?

```
xargs -d'\n' -a file.list rename -n 's/\.bed$//'
```